# android opengl texture drawing wrong texture

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

I have a drawing thread and a separate thread for events. When the renderer starts, I can create as many textures I want without any problem. But when I try to add a new texture in the separate thread, the texture will become another one. Say if I have tex1, tex2 and tex3 created at startup, and I want to add tex4 on the fly, tex4 will look as tex1, but with its own dimensions (tex1 stretched to tex4 size). If I add more textures, they will look like the previous ones. tex5 will look like tex2 and tex6 like tex3.

This would be even ok, because I could shift something, but after all the preloaded textures are "used up", the new textures will be white.

So in short, at startup I can add any textures, but the textures added after take the ones loaded at the start in order, and then are just blank.

The code for texture creation

```
gl.glGenTextures(1, texture_handler, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_handler[0]);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uvs.length * 4);
    tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = tbb.asShortBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(uvs);
    textureBuffer.position(0);
```

And the code for drawing

```
Utils.gl.glLoadIdentity();
    Utils.gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    Utils.gl.glScalef(width, height, 1);
    Utils.gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textImage[0]);
    Utils.gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_SHORT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    Utils.gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_SHORT, 0, textureBuffer);
    Utils.gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Adding numbers to `textImage[0]` like `textImage[0]+1` shows another texture, but it seems the newly added textures are nowhere to be found.

Comment: What device are you running on?

Comment: You create separate contexts for the two threads, with the contexts being in the same share group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I figured out something.
I ran it on two devices, a telephone and a tablet, it wasn't working on either.
I don't know what is a shared context group, but thanks for the tip, [Reto Koradi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3530129/reto-koradi), it helped.

As for the thing I do wrong, I don't quite understand them. I thought I bind my texture with glBindTexture. If I put texture_handler[0] in glGenTextures(), it gives me an error, because it expects int[]. glactivetexture does not change much, so I don't use it.

It works now, this is how I resolved it:
I don't execute the binding script in the separate thread, I just set a variable to 1, and in the onDraw of the renderer I check for the variable, and bind it in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

It was wrong that...

1. you never bind that you generated.

   gl.glGenTextures(1, texture_handler, 0); //texture_handler should be texture_handler[0]
   gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_handler[0]);

   Utils.gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textImage[0]); // where texImage[0] comes from? It must be what you generated by  glGenTextures(1, ttexImage[0]);
2. If you have multiple textures, you should call glactivetexture(texture unit number) before bind a texture